# What happens to Yusuke's spirit/power equipment?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

Started watching Yu Yu Hakusho on blu ray now, about 10 years after I first saw it as a kid.  Wondering what happens to Yusuke's various power equipment. I recall in the first few episodes he needs some kind of ring/band that helps recharge and focus his spirit engergy for spirit gun... then it just goes away, at least in season 1. Does he still have them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're still around. Botan mentions both the [Communication Mirror](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Communication_Mirror) and the [Demon Compass](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Demon_Compass) during the Chapter Black Saga.

The devices start to lose their usefulness as the series turns into a fighting series. Being able to track a demon or [have X Ray vision](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Psychic_Spyglass) aren't terribly useful in a fight against Toguro or Sensui. As for the ring, apparently it [makes Yusuke severely exhausted](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Concentration_Ring) after he uses it; I recall him passing out after he uses it against Gouki and needing to be picked up and brought home by Boutan. He needed it early on when his own spirit energy was fairly weak, but later on, after he trains with Genkai and starts to gain power, the tradeoffs of the ring become more of a liability than a benefit. Presumably he still has it, though, he just doesn't use it because it's not helpful.

Comment: I would think that if the ring multiplies his attack force, it'd always be useful regardless of the exhaustion factor. I guess Ill have to finish the series to find out.

Comment: @V1GG3N I'm pretty sure he never uses it again. That was just an in-universe theory about why. His later fights tend to be drawn out and the opponents are smarter, stronger, and faster than Gouki, so it's a big risk for him to pass out if he misses or if his one blast still isn't strong enough. Out of universe, the author probably just forgot about it or didn't feel like using it.